# Abnormal display on laptop screen

Tags: drivers, 22.04, graphics, display, intel-graphics

My laptop screen did not display properly when I installed Ubuntu 22.04. The display is out of place in the middle (horizontally), and the screen flickers. The computer graphics card is an 11th-generation Intel Xe integrated graphics card, how do I solve this problem? My laptop model is HUAWEI Matebook E 2021.

[image: Here is the picture showing the problem]

Comment: Does it happen on a 23.10 LiveCD? If not, it looks like a hardware problem

Comment: No. It happened on a 22.04.4 liveCD. And after finishing the installation, it still happened

Comment: Does it happen if you ***switch to*** a 23.10 LiveCD?

Comment: Yes,when i switch to a 23.10LiveCD, it happened too. And when displaying the ubuntu and manufacturer ICONS during the booting, the problem happened.

Comment: This is a hardware problem if it doesn't happen on Windows. I don't think there is any fix on Ubuntu. You could try changing resolution or Hz but that's it

Comment: After a few tries, i.switch to linux mint's compatibility mode, and it works well except brightness adjustment, so i add this parameter to ubuntu grub, **irqpoll nosplash nomodeset**, and it works!